# A bound on the balanced equipartition of a multi-set of integers

Tags: combinatorics

A balanced equipartition of a multi-set of $2n$ integers is a partition into two multi-sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ of size $n$ such that the sum of the integers in $S_1$ is as close as possible as the sum of the integers in $S_2$. Let's call the gap between those two sums the value of the balanced equipartition.

Do we know a bound on the value of the equipartition when all the integers range from $0$ to $Cn$ for a constant $C$?

Comment: What sort of bound are you looking for, 'it can be at least as bad as $X$' or 'it will never be worse than $Y$' or both?  (Great question, incidentally!)

Comment: I am more interested in 'it will never be worse than Y'.

Answer (score 1):

If our original multi-set $S$ has a single occurrence of $Cn$ and $2n-1$ $~0$s, then the value of the equipartition is $Cn$. The value of any equipartition will never be worse than $Cn$ because that is the maximum difference between two elements of the multi-set. We can guarantee that the value of the equipartition is at most this by applying the algorithm:

1. $S_1=S_2=\emptyset$
2. While $S\ne\emptyset$: remove elements $x$ and $y$ from $S$, and WLOG assume $x\geq y$. If $\sum\limits_{i\in S_1} i\leq \sum\limits_{j\in S_2} j$ place $x$ in $S_1$ and $y$ in $S_2$. Else place $y$ in $S_1$ and $x$ in $S_2$.

Placing according to this algorithm maintains $|\sum\limits_{i\in S_1} i-\sum\limits_{j\in S_2}j|\leq\max\limits_{x,~y~\in S}{|x-y|}\leq Cn$.

Comment: The worst possible value is $Cn^2$ which can only occur when $S_1$ contains purely $0$s and $S_2$ contains purely $Cn$s.

Comment: I'd missed the 'multiset' aspect of this; your first example is a great one.  I wonder what the answer starts to look like if we consider sets rather than multisets, though...

Comment: Thanks, Peter. Right, Steven, it is more interesting with sets. The value might be always constant. If you try Peter's trick with $S$ having integer $Cn$ and the $2n-1$ integers from $0$ to $2n-2$, put in $S_1$, $\{Cn\} \cup [0,i]$ and in $S_2$, $[2n-i+1,2n-2]$ where $i$ is the greatest integer such that the sum in $S_1$ is greater than the sum in $S_2$. Assuming $n>C$, $i$ is well defined. Then, you add $2n-i$ to $S_2$ and $j \in [i+1,2n-i-1]$ such that the partial sum of $S_1$ and $S_2$ matches. Then, equipartitioning $[i+1,2n-i-1]\setminus\{j\}$ can easily be done with constant value.